# How to update compiler to Swift 2?

Tags: swift

I installed XCode 7 Beta, when I open playground it says:

> Playground execution terminated because the process stopped unexpectedly.

I run swift in terminal and it says:

> Apple Swift version 1.2 (swiftlang-602.0.53.1 clang-602.0.53)
>   Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0

How can i update my swift version to 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens when you have different copies of Xcode IDE installed

Use `xcode-select` command line utility to select the version of Xcode that you wanna use

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcode-select.1.html

```
$ xcode-select --switch /path/to/the/Xcode
```